# Multiple web templates for a website?

Tags: usability, user-centered-design

Is it OK to use multiple (probably 2) dashboard templates for a website?

My web app has two components: a general discussion forum with profiles and a one-to-one chat section, and a section that provides analytics of individual users and their activity.

During the early development stages, I chose a web template with a UI that looks very nice in the first part, but not with the other. Should I use this template for both parts, or use different templates for each part according to what looks good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consistency is one of the most important design principles. Do not make the web app look too different from one section to the other otherwise users will be confused about the overall functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases like this, the user who wants to view the analytics is different from the users who are on the discussion forum. While consistency is the general rule in UX, it is helpful to provide an experience that is best for each of those types of users (personas).

Wordpress, for example, can look very different when the administrator logs into the back end. This helps the administrator become immediately oriented as to where they are in the site, and lowers their cognitive load.

Therefore, I think it would be fine to use a different template to review analytics if that's not something that most of the forum's users will access, especially if it provides a much better experience for the analytics user.